# PHP, indentation width of 4, and CodeSniffer: is "4" a de-facto standard?

Tags: php, indentation

I've asked a question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/php-codesniffer-indentation-of-2-is-ignored-it-just-checks-4/28512) because all my Php code is indented by 2, not 4.

Php CodeSniffer, which is a really great tool, has an indentation of "4" and it seems you can't change that value.

Php CodeSniffer has a lot of options. So this it should be easy to add "indentation width". But it seems the creators have **voluntary** avoided the possibility, because it's not possible (which is weird IMHO).

So if you can't change this, I was wondering: is "indentation width = 4" a de-facto standard?

Is this the same for Java / JavaDoc generation ?

Do I have to change all my 10.000+ lines of code to a 4 - indendation width?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any public member var in sniffs can be overwritten by using a ruleset.xml file. A ruleset.xml file is an XML representation of your own custom coding standard. It can import sniffs from any of the included standards and can also include your own custom sniffs if you choose to write them.

In your case, you want the exact PEAR standard, but with the indent value changed. So create a file `mystandard.xml` and make this the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
 <description>My custom PEAR coding standard.</description>
 <rule ref="PEAR"/>
 <rule ref="PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
  <properties>
   <property name="indent" value="2"/>
  </properties>
 </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Now, instead of running PHP_CodeSniffer using the command `phpcs --standard=PEAR ...` you use `phpcs --standard=/path/to/mystandard.xml ...`

Note that you can call the standard anything you want and change the XML metadata (name and description) to something more appropriate.

There is a lot more you can do with a custom ruleset.xml file. You can find more information about custom rulesets here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.annotated-ruleset.php

Comment: Thank you bud. You're still a life saver, 6 years later.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not a de-facto standard. There is no standard for indentation.

You can choose rules using --sniffs -- see the [manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.usage.php). You don't need to do the indentation test.

If PHP CodeSniffer was any good, it would be possible to define the indentation style in your coding standard. There is no mention of it in the documentation though.

Alternatively, you can write your own rule as described here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I'll check it one day if I want to make my own rules.

Answer (score 1):

What i've found in `PHP_CodeSniffer\CodeSniffer\Standards\Generic\Sniffs\WhiteSpace\ScopeIndentSniff.php` is `public $indent = 4;`.

You might just want to change this value.

Comment: This is the right solution. I didn't want to re-define my whole standard, because I find PEAR to be a really nice standard.

Comment: @OlivierPons: Extend from that standard, change the value.

Answer (score 0):

PHP CodeSniffer has rules, from what I know you should be able to create one that defines the indentation. 4 is just some value, like 2. So should work. Probably not as an option but within when you define your standard.